# All-in re-steal on bubble

Tags: texas-hold-em, tournament, all-in, mtt

It was a bubble stage of a live Satellite MTT. 5 tickets awarded, 7 players left out of 30, quite loose table. I have A8o on SB with 13bb, MP limps, Button(20bb) raises 2.5bb. I push all-in, MP folds, Button calls with KK and wins the hand.

Now I think that I might have needed to fold that A8o cause calling and playing it postflop would be difficult. What would be the correct play considering different steal ranges of the opp?

Comment: What shorter stacks than you were there left? Presumably 6th was paying a cash prize less than the value of the seat the sat was for if you're saying it was the bubble?

Comment: @Jeff you need to mention the stacks of all 7 players in order for us to form a proper answer. ICM is a huge part of your decision here and you left us in the dark.

Comment: @3N1GM4 sorry for late reply, I was the shortest stack. 6th wasn't paying cash.

Comment: Ok, so you weren't on the bubble then? 7 players left with 5 seats available to win?

Comment: @3N1GM4 well almost a bubble

Answer (score 3):

Agree push fold.

Behind a limp that is a relatively small raise.  You are getting 2 : 1 to call.   That could very well be a value raise in position with a good or very good hand and happy if it picks up the pot or isolates.

You are dominated by a bigger ace and any pair 8+. You are behind a smaller pair.  You are only 57% against J9. In ICM 57% all in is not a good bet. Btn is getting 2:1 to call your raise in position and they have you covered. You don't have enough fold equity. Are you hoping to fold out J9?  No reason for the btn to try and steal here with T7 behind a limp.

Open push with A8o from mid to late - yes.  Behind a limp and a raise - no.

Comment: I like your answer when stacks are all even, but it all depends on the other stacks. If there are 3 other stacks with 1 BB, you even have to fold aces in this spot. You might want to add that.

Comment: @RaymondTimmermans Aces is not the question.

Comment: @paprazzi ok fine. With A8o it might not be an open push depending on the stacks, due to icm. You might want to add that.